# Extract PDF form data and submit to MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdf

I am developing an application using PHP and MYSQL. I would like to present some of my users with an editable PDF form and be able to extract the data and submit it in a MySQL database table. I have done some reading around and came across PDFtk but it doesn't seem to serve my purpose.Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction on how I can do this using PHP.Thanks

Comment: Why does it matter that it's a PDF? Surely, from the point of view of  the user, it's just a form?

Comment: the client wants it as a PDF document. Tried convincing them otherwise without any success

Comment: So they would double-click a PDF, edit it, and then somehow those edits would be transferred to a database?

Comment: Yes something like that,Its an editable PDF document.I have seen some questions here on SO with people saying they have been able to do it,but nothing useful yet